# Submit form with a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a small search form that can perform two types of searches:

```
<form id="form-navbar-search" class="navbar-search pull-left" action="index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.output" method="post">
   <div class="input-append">
      <input type="text" name="header_search_criteria" title="Criteria to search" placeholder="search" class="search-query span9" />
      <input type="submit" name="quick" value="Quick" title="Search on task ID or task name" class="btn btn-inverse" />
      <a href="index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.home" id="navbar-search-full" title="Start a full search" class="btn btn-inverse" />Full</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

1. If the "Quick" submit button is pressed, the form submits to the
   default action attribute (`index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.output`). This works.
2. If
   the "Full" button (it's really an `a` that I'm styling as a
   button using Bootstrap) is pressed, I want to prevent the link from opening a new
   page, change the form's action to `index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.home`, then submit the form. I have written this jQuery to do so:

```
$('#navbar-search-full').click( function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); //don't let the link open a new page
   $('#form-navbar-search').attr('action',  $(this).attr('href')).submit(); //instead, change the search form action, then submit it
})
.attr('href','#navbar-search-full');
```

As [you can see in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/cgcDy/), the preventDefault() doesn't seem to intercept the link action. **What adjustments do I need to make to get this right?**

Comment: I see a different problem: you're changing the href of `#navbar-search-full` *before* the click handler can be triggered.

Comment: Hmm...so the last line of the JS sets the href of the link to `#navbar-search-full`, then that `#navbar-search-full` href is getting set as the form's action?

Comment: Yup, that was it. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/cgcDy/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a different problem: you're changing the href of `#navbar-search-full` before the click handler can be triggered.

Try moving `.attr('href','#navbar-search-full')` inside the `click` handler, before the form is submitted, or just remove it entirely.

Comment: Actually, it occurs to me that if I'm preventing the link's action, I don't have to worry about the link firing, so I don't have to change it's href. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/cgcDy/10/ This is nice because it will even work if JavaScript is not available!

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;
```

This will work for you...

**EDIT**

you could have the anchors href="#" and then use a "data-" attribute to store your URL. Then the anchor wouldnt have any action and you could retrieve the attribute in the same way using .attr("data-").. with whatever you decide to call it..

Comment: The "button" is a link (`a`); nothing is submitting the form, so there's no form submission to intercept. Put another way, the `a` is firing before my jQuery fires the form submission.

Comment: you could have the anchors href="#" and then use a "data-" attribute to store your URL. Then the anchor wouldnt have any action and you could retrieve the attribute in the same way using .attr("data-").. with whatever you decide to call it...